# raspberry pi controlling relay, led on relay lights up but NO switch not closing

Tags: raspberry-pi3, relay

I hear no switching sounds from relay.

I connected

JD-VCC to Pin2 (5V)

GND to Pin6 (Ground)

IN1 to pin7 (Gpio4)

VCC to Pin1 (3V)

Connected 240V DC to NO and COM.

gpio export 4 out lets the led on the relay lighten in red.

What is going wrong?

This project shall replace and old viessmann alogue time switch by a switch controlled by pi. .

Is my setup and wiring correct? I am sorry this is my first pi project. Can someone please double check the setup and wiring?

This is the old clock case:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your images, so forgive me, but is it possible your relay takes 5v to close the switch? Have you tried just using plain wires to a 5v source to see if it's your relay or your pi?

Comment: I figured out that those connections work,


Raspberry 5v(Pin2) to VCC of 2 channel relay,


Raspberry GND(Pin6) to GND of 2 channel relay,


Raspberry GPIO 04(Pin7) to IN1 of 2 channel relay,


RaspbRaspberry GPIO 27(Pin11) to IN2 of 2 channel relay